# Casting object to interface type with no TInterfacedObject as base class

Tags: delphi, interface, delphi-xe2

I need a class implementing interface with no reference counting. I did the following:

```
  IMyInterface = interface(IInterface)
      ['{B84904DF-9E8A-46E0-98E4-498BF03C2819}'] 
      procedure InterfaceMethod;
  end;

  TMyClass = class(TObject, IMyInterface)
  protected
      function _AddRef: Integer;stdcall;
      function _Release: Integer;stdcall;
      function QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult;stdcall;
  public
      procedure InterfaceMethod;
  end;

  procedure TMyClass.InterfaceMethod;
  begin
      ShowMessage('The Method');
  end;

  function TMyClass.QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult;
  begin
      if GetInterface(IID, Obj) then
          Result := 0
      else
          Result := E_NOINTERFACE;
  end;

  function TMyClass._AddRef: Integer;
  begin
      Result := -1;
  end;

  function TMyClass._Release: Integer;
  begin
      Result := -1;
  end;
```

Lack of reference counting works fine. But my concern is that I cannot cast `TMyClass` to `IMyInterface` using `as` operator:

```
var
  MyI: IMyInterface; 
begin
  MyI := TMyClass.Create as IMyInterface;
```

I am given

> [DCC Error] E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type

The problem disappears when `TMyClass` derives from `TInterfacedObject` - i.e. I can do such casting without compiler error. Obviously I do not want to use TInterfacedObject as a base class as it would make my class reference counted. Why is such casting disallowed and how one would workaround it?

Comment: You might have better results by adding a GUID to your interface declaration. Add a new line after the `= interface` line and press Ctrl-Shft-G. `as`, `GetInterface` and `supports` etc need to be able to identify the interface by GUID to work.

Comment: You did not read my post carefully. when I derive from TInterfacedObject it works. GUID has nothing to do here. You need GUID only to operate with COM.

Comment: Hmm, which Delphi version?

Comment: I am currently using XE2. I will edit tag list.

Comment: And no, you don't just need GUIDs for working with COM. You need GUIDs to work with interfaces in many respects. Have you tried adding a GUID and seeing what happens?

Comment: After adding GUID same thing. I will edit my code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: you got it I think. I didn't spot the lack of IInterface in the class' declaration as the methods did appear in the class.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan after adding IInterface to the list it works. Could you post an answer so I can accept it with some explanation maybe?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason you cannot use `as` in your code is that your class does not explicitly list `IInterface` in its list of supported interfaces. Even though your interface derives from `IInterface`, unless you actually list that interface, your class does not support it.

So, the trivial fix is to declare your class like this:

```
TMyClass = class(TObject, IInterface, IMyInterface)
```

The reason that your class needs to implement `IInterface` is that is what the compiler is relying on in order to implement the `as` cast.

The other point I would like to make is that you should, in general, avoid using interface inheritance. By and large it serves little purpose. One of the benefits of using interfaces is that you are free from the single inheritance constraint that comes with implementation inheritance.

But in any case, all Delphi interfaces [automatically inherit from `IInterface`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Object_Interfaces#IInterface_and_Inheritance) so in your case there's no point specifying that. I would declare your interface like this:

```
IMyInterface = interface
  ['{B84904DF-9E8A-46E0-98E4-498BF03C2819}'] 
  procedure InterfaceMethod;
end;
```

More broadly you should endeavour not to use inheritance with your interfaces. By taking that approach you will encourage less coupling and that leads to greater flexibility.

Comment: Interface inheritance is **not** implementation inheritance. Also any interface in Delphi is derived from `IInterface`. The last sentence is unclear.

Comment: @Serg That interface inheritance is **not** implementation inheritance is precisely the point I'm trying to make. I'll try and clear it up.

Comment: It also worth mentioning that the use interface inheritance decreases an instance size. Whether you use `TMyClass = class(TObject, IMyInterface)` or `TMyClass = class(TObject, IInterface, IMyInterface)` an instance size is 12 bytes in Delphi XE because `IMyInterface` inherits from `IInterface`. Explicit declaration of `IInterface` support is important at compile-time only and does not bloat code even a bit.

Comment: @David, you most likely wanted to write "...avoid using interface inheritance" instead of "...avoid using implementation inheritance". I think that "typo" confused Serg

Comment: @iamjoosy Yes that's it. Thank you. Now fixed. I'm also not wild about implementation inheritance, but that's a different story!

Comment: @David, in addition to your reasons for not using interface inheritance another point leading to confusion is the different behavior of interface vs class inheritance.

Comment: Just as addition to my todays experience, I forgot to add the GUID on my interface and AS operator was not allowed with compiler error. I totally forgot about that and was blind for the fact.